# Unable to import InAppBillingService

Tags: android, libraries, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement in app billing in my app, but I just can not find the library. Acording to my SDK manager I have already installed the library, but I am not able to find it anywhere on my computer.

Based on information I found at the documentation pages I found out that it should be located at in the android SDK folder at /extras/google/google_play_services/ but I am not able to find it.

I know that you are supposed to import it through file > import > android > existing android code into Workspace and this is not the problem.

Have I not instaled it corectly or am I just not able to find the file on my Windows computer?

Comment: Check `Window->Preferences...Android` screen. At the top is the root location of your SDK, open than folder and look for the `/extras/google/google_play_services/` in there.

Comment: @iagreen Found the file. Write it as an answear and I accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `Window->Preferences...Android` screen. At the top is the root location of your SDK, open than folder and look for the `/extras/google/google_play_services/` in there.  Then import as you suggest in your question.